# HighCharts - how to speed up selecting and deselecting series?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I was able to create a Highcharts that shows 10,000 points with 30 series and while initial drawing seems fast - selecting and deselecting series seems very slow (used booster lib):
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3707wefa/)

```
type: 'scatter'
```

End goal is to have 50,000 points with 20-30 series and selecting/deselecting from the chart to be fast. Is it possible to achieve? Maybe it should be written differently?

Please help. thanks

Comment: I think you should define "slow", because the fiddle is almost instantaneous on my PC.

Comment: Slow for selecting and deselecting any 1 series. It takes more than 10sec for any series de/selection..

Comment: @Joe you mean clicking on the series in the legend?

Comment: At the beginning I advice you to sort your data by x ascending. Secondly you can try to use the Highstock. https://jsfiddle.net/g8vsqeo5/

Comment: @Sebastion - I will try that.. 'apokryfos' - yes selecting by clicking on the series in the legend (is there another way to deselect/select series?)

Comment: I would suggest making sure animation is turned off, shadows are disabled, tooltips are disabled, mouseTracking is disabled, etc.  But I guess my bigger question is what do you hope to achieve with this chart? What is a user going to be able to get out of 50,000 points plotted so densely with a giant list of series names to look through and click on?

Comment: The thing is that user does not know how many different series will get before the action on the web (which pulls the data from db). And they want to quickly deselect several series, compare data from one series to another (e.g. series 1-5 with series 10-12) and then some other combination (many different combinations of series) for 1 big data set.That is why performance of selecting / deselecting is important to them..

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan - tried sorting data but did not help in this case..